# Update description in elastic beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

How can we update the elastic beanstalk description in the AWS Console home?

Is there a way to do it there or it is only through CLI?

Answer (score 0):

What do you want to update on Elastic Beanstalk? I am assuming you mean an application. You can also use the AWS SDK to update an Elastic Beanstalk app. For example, if you are using the [AWS SDK for Java V2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/home.html), you can use this method:

https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/elasticbeanstalk/ElasticBeanstalkClient.html#updateApplication-software.amazon.awssdk.services.elasticbeanstalk.model.UpdateApplicationRequest-